# Is there a way to control opacity/transparency of the border color using CSS?

Tags: css, transparency, border, opacity

Is there a way to control opacity/transparency of the border color using CSS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try rgba color

```
border-color: rgb(255,255,255); /* fallback for IE */
border-color: rgba(255,255,255, 0.4); /* RGBA for the ones supporting it */
```

The last one is the (alpha) opacity.
But it's not supported in IE, that's why you need a fallback version

Comment: This doesn't work in ANY browser, because the background color of the element is behind the border.

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to achieve. He accepted it, so it means his problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try `border: 5px solid rgba(255,0,0,0.5);` -- the alpha channel is the last parameter.

NOTE: Not all browsers (read: Internet Explorer) support this.